# Hp Fortify Apache Camel

Tags: apache, security, apache-camel, fortify

How can I get Apache to fix HP Fortify findings in Apache Camel? I tried to post on their forums about getting assistance, but Apache has not given a clear answer to what steps I should take to fix these findings. They said on there site that fixing bugs in their code is a priority, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Kev, you are stepping on peoples toes with statements like that. ASF responds well to its community and users. Go read this page which tells you how to report findings: http://camel.apache.org/support

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but you can raise issues in the [official bugtracker for Apache Camel](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL).

I think it will also help to share your findings and your thoughts about what and how to fix with the [developers mailing list](https://camel.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).